# How to find Area of Triangle when you mess up?

Tags: triangles, area

[Orginal Question like this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4464189/how-to-find-the-area-of-a-triangle?noredirect=1#comment9353907_4464189)

So I thought the base was 32 feet and the height was 16 feet but when I did 1/2 times 32 times 15 and got 265 inches squared. What have I done wrong?

[Problem I don't Understand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xV8mA.png)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136841/discussion-on-question-by-nora-smith-how-to-find-area-of-triangle-when-you-mess).

Answer (score 1):

Just to illustrate peterwhy's suggestion, split up the trapezoid into two triangles (for instance, along the red dotted line below):

[image]

Both triangles have a height of $16$ ft. The upper triangle has a base of length $18$ ft, and the other triangle has a base of $32$ ft.

The area of the trapezoid is then the sum of the areas of the two triangles, which are

$$\text{area of upper triangle: } \frac12 \times 18 \,\mathrm{ft} \times 16 \,\mathrm {ft} = 144 \,\mathrm{ft}^2$$

$$\text{area of lower triangle: } \frac12 \times 32\,\mathrm{ft} \times 16\,\mathrm{ft} = 256\,\mathrm{ft}^2$$

and hence

$$\text{area of trapezoid: } 144\,\mathrm{ft}^2 + 256\,\mathrm{ft}^2 = 400\,\mathrm{ft}^2$$

Comment: Thank you I will keep this in mind for next time.